# combining multiple text files into csv in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 text files:

[image: text file 1] [image: text file 2]

I want to make a CSV file with the data and add a column based on the header. Like this:

[image: expected output].

I wrote this:

```py
import glob 
import pandas as pd

files = sorted(glob.glob('content/*.txt'))
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, files))

df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\srava\OneDrive - Deakin University\Desktop\final\combined.csv")
```

But the output doesn't match what I want:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will break your problem into 3 parts:

1. Get column name from header. For that I will read it using read_csv. But it may not be most optimised way. But it will do for small files.
2. Read all files and skip first row. Give same column names.
3. Add column with respective header value.
   We can achieve it using following code:

> ```
> import glob 
> import pandas as pd
>
> files = sorted(glob.glob('content/*.txt'))
> dfs = []
> for file in files:
>     column_name = pd.read_csv(file,index_col=False).columns[0]
>     df = pd.read_csv(file,index_col=False,names=["col1","col2"],skiprows=1)
>     df["col3"] = column_name
>     dfs.append(df)
> df = pd.concat(dfs)
> ```

[image]

Comment: thank you as you said it works for small files, but I have 1000 files each with 55000 records each

Comment: You can always get first character of file using some efficient python csv code. Have you tested with 1000 files? If it works, please accept my answer.